# Does a wedding on Yom Yerushalayim exempt the couple from fasting?

Tags: halacha, fast-days, wedding, yom-yerushalayim

I attended a wedding last Sunday, which was [Yom Yerushalayim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerusalem_Day). The chattan and Kallah did not fast as they claimed that since it was a day when they did not say *Tachanun*, and they said *Halel*, it was considered similar to Rosh Hodesh or other holiday that would exempt them from fasting.

I didn't have time to ask the *chatan* of the source for this ruling. Is someone aware of anyone that rules this way?

Comment: Hopefully the *chatan*'s Rabbi ;-)

Comment: @Yishai And the _kallah_'s Rabbi as well.

Comment: @DoubleAA, now there is an obscure question - could one be obligated to fast but not the other?

Comment: @Yishai I don't see why not. To whatever extent the husband's side determines family Minhagim, why would that apply prior to the wedding? Even without that argument, if they both asked different poskim (about any given safek) it may be Asur for them to practice like the other's poseik.

Comment: Is fasting before the wedding obligatory?

Comment: @Yishai I believe Rav Moshe Soloveichik, z"l, following the ruling of his father Rav Chaim, z"l, did not fast the day of his wedding, though his wife Pesha Feinstein, a"h, following the ruling of her father, Rav Elyah, z"l, did. (Actually the story is that he told her she didn't have to because of his father's ruling, at which point she informed him that "in Pruzhan we have our own poskim.")

Answer (score 6):

A Chosson [fasts on Yom Yerushalaim](http://www.din.org.il/2015/06/18/%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%9D-%D7%91%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D-%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D/)

Comment: This answer would be more valuable if it included a reference describing the authority it cites. In addition, given that the question asked for sources indicating that a chosson does not fast, this answer doesn't yet directly address the question. If it included logic that somehow extrapolated from this source that no contrary source *could* exist, it would be a complete answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Not saying tachanun is not necessarily a reason to not fast on the wedding day... see here http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/481616/jewish/Fasting-On-the-Wedding-Day.htm gives examples when one would fast despite those days not having tachanun.

All the more so on an unestablished holiday with little halachic support that one should fast on the day of one's wedding

Comment: What makes it "unestablished"? And it certainly has plenty of Halakhic support, so that claim is simply false.